# How can fire the click event button automatically

Tags: reactjs, button

I have a download button in my page,I want to trigger it automatically when render to this page, how can I do that? I read some answers from Stack Overflow to useRef(), but I still do not quite understand how to apply it.

My download function:

```js
const downloadHandler = async (e) => {

    const getNewCategory = async () => {
        await axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:3001/download",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      }).then(res => {
        setNCategory(res.data)
        console.log("res.data: "+JSON.stringify(res.data));
      });
    }

     getNewCategory()
}
```

My button:

```html
<div className="field">
    <div className="control">
        <button type="button" onClick={downloadHandler} className="btn-small">
             Download
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an id to your button

```
<button id="download" type="button" onClick={downloadHandler} className="btn-small">
```

Then you can manually trigger click event

```
const downloadButton = document.getElementById('download');

downloadButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
  'view': window,
  'bubbles': true,
  'cancelable': false
}));
```

Call it like above where you needed

**UPDATE**
Using ref, here's the way

We define our ref

```
const downloadButton = useRef(null);
```

and use it on or button

```
<button ref={downloadButton} type="button" onClick={downloadHandler} className="btn-small">
```

then trigger click event

```
downloadButton.current.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
  'view': window,
  'bubbles': true,
  'cancelable': false
}));
```

Comment: Got this error => Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dispatchEvent')

Comment: I have updated my answer with an alternative

Comment: Got the same error! Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Where do you use it?

Comment: Your button should be existing in the DOM when you call it, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: The first solution works, thanks!

Comment: Cool! Congrats..